# pre_get_posts - Trying to get property of non-object warning

Tags: wp-query, query, pre-get-posts

This code outputs the following warning when run on the `pre_get_posts` action:

`Trying to get property of non-object`

Which points to this line:

`if( 'edit' == $screen->base && 'my_post_type' == $screen->post_type && $order_by == '0' ) {`

Why am I getting this warning?

```
    public function my_post_type_default_sort( $query ){

        if( !is_admin() ) {
            return;
        }

        $screen = get_current_screen();

        if( !isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
            $order_by = '0';
        }

        if( 'edit' == $screen->base && 'my_post_type' == $screen->post_type && $order_by == '0' ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'scr_date' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try dumping `$screen` and check what it contains at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$screen` may not be available yet when `pre_get_posts` fires. Try this instead:

```
public function my_post_type_default_sort( $query ){
    if(!isset($_GET['orderby']) && is_admin()) {
        $orderby = '0';
    }
    if($query->is_main_query() && is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('my_post_type') && $orderby=0) {
        $query->set('orderby','scr_date');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, `$screen` is only available on the admin side, and the beginning of their `pre_get_posts` is telling it to run on non-admin pages.